# delete from array returning self

Tags: ruby

If I want to delete some elements from an Array and return itself, are foo1 and foo2 below (foo2 when there is only one element to delete) the right way to do it?

```
class Array
    def foo1 *args; delete_if{|x| args.include?(x)} end
    def foo2 arg; delete(arg); self end
end
```

Comment: It seems you could do with just passing an array to delete_if and use that without monkey-patching Array.

Comment: [1, 2, 3].delete_if([2, 4]) gives back an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Array
 def foo3 (*args); self - args; end
end
```

Comment: actually, what I want would be self -= args

Answer (score 0):

```
array.reject{|element| element == value_of_element_to_be_deleted}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ugly, but the minus function does the trick concisely, subtracting one array from the other:

```
ary = [1, 2, 99, 3]
ary.-([99])
```

or

```
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 99]
ary.-(odds)
```

The advantage here is that it is completely chainable (unlike `.delete` or `ary - odds`), so you can do things like:

```
ary.-(odds).average
```

Once your eye finds the minus sign, it's much easier to read, understand, and visually spot typos than the `.delete_if` construct.

It also plays well with Ruby's safe navigation operator, `&.`, if you might get nil instead of an array. That's something you can't do elegantly with subtracting arrays.

```
maybe_array&.-(odds)&.average
```