# Array#delete, but return the array?

Tags: ruby

Is there a built-in method which performs the same function as `Array#delete` but returns `self`? I'd like to do it without using a block and clearer than `an_ary.-([el])`.

I could monkeypatch one, but it seems like a "compact with arguments" method would be a relatively common desire?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094283/delete-from-array-returning-self

Comment: Nearly. I'm just wondering if there is a built-in method, really. I'll clarify a bit.

Comment: `ary.delete_if{ |e| e == elem }` isn't very clear or concise. Why bother having `Array#compact` if we can just `delete_if{ |e| e.nil? }`?

Comment: Your `an_ary.-([el])`, or `an_ary-[el]`, is the simplest form you can get. it only has one method `-`, and takes an argument `[el]`, without which there is no way to say what you want to remove. If you don't like the method name `-`, then maybe you can alias it to some other method.

Comment: but it won't touch `any_ary` as far as `delete_if` will. only if `any_ary = an_ary-[el]`

Comment: @fl00r In that case, use `an_ary-=[el]`

Comment: yeap, that's definitely shorter :)

Comment: @sawa it's not the method name I dislike, it's requiring the argument to also be an array. It can potentially get confusing when I'm trying to remove an element which is also an array, like `ary.-([[1, 2]])`. Ideally `reject`, `reject!`, `delete`, and `delete_if` would be brought further in line with the other destructive and synonymous methods.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you want to mutate the original array, like `delete`, here are options:

```
ary.reject!{|e| e==42 }.something_else
ary.tap{|a| a.delete 42}.something_else
(ary.delete 42;ary).something_else
(ary-=[42]).something_else
```

If you want a new array to chain from:

```
ary.reject{|e| e==42 }.something_else
(ary-[42]).something_else
```

Comment: @gamov Define "overheads" and then you can test and benchmark yourself.

Answer (score 6):

`an_ary.-([el])` looks awful.

What about...

```py
an_ary - [el]
```

?

The most natural way of dealing with mathematical operations is this...

```py
4 - 2
```

Not this...

```py
4.-(2)
```

Comment: It looks a bit ugly...but is the most succinct solution, IMO. It allows chaining, and particularly, it allows chaining with `&.`

Comment: Succinct? `an_ary - [el]` is more succint on all scenarios. If you don't want to count the spaces, it has 3 less characters. If you want to count the spaces, it has 1 less character. But I don't prefer this solution for succinctness, I prefer for readability/comprehensibility. `an_ary - [el]` is clear even for new developers (same syntax as python for example), while `an_ary.-([el])` is more complex. It just blurs a trivial operation. The other solution allows chaining, but we are not chaining on the first place. I can quote Occam's Razor: “the simplest solution is almost always the best."

Comment: Yes, I think you're right, regarding succinctness. My bad.

Comment: This worked for me, I was hoping for a method to do this, but ended up with something like: `(item[0..6] - [item[1]])`

Answer (score 4):

```
array.reject{|element| element == value_of_element_to_be_deleted}
```

Comment: `reject` - Returns a new array containing the items in self for which the given block is not true. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
my_array.first(n) #1

my_array.last(n) #2
```

If the elements of the array you want to delete, are at the end (1) or at the beginning (2) of the array.

Comment: I prefer this solution, but don't know about its performance comparing with other solutions though.

Comment: Not too keen on this - what happens if someone else changes the array's order at a later date?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same question for `Array#delete_at` that returned an array with the element at a specified index removed, which is why I ended up here. Looks like it isn't built in. In case anyone else is interested, I quickly wrote this monkey patch (I gave this virtually no thought regarding efficiency, and I originally didn't handle any cases such as negative indices or out of bounds indices...but then I decided to quick throw a couple in there):

```
class Array
  def remove_at(i)
    # handle index out of bounds by returning unchanged array
    return self if i >= self.length

    # remove the i-th element from the end if i is negative
    if i < 0
      i += self.length
      # handle index out of bounds by returning unchanged array
      return self if i < 0
    end

    # Return an array composed of the elements before the specified
    # index plus the elements after the specified index
    return self.first(i) + self.last(self.length - i - 1)
  end
end

test = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
puts test.remove_at(3).inspect
puts test.remove_at(5).inspect
puts test.remove_at(6).inspect
puts test.remove_at(-7).inspect
puts test.remove_at(-2).inspect
```

I had fun whipping this up, so I figured I might as well post it here :)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this way:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
list.tap { |list| list.delete(2) } # => [1, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -1):

The OP doesn't like the look of `an_ary.-([el])` ... but it really does have a lot going for it.

True...it's a little ugly, but the minus method does the trick concisely, subtracting one array from the other:

```
ary = [1, 2, 99, 3]
ary.-([99])
```

or

```
odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 99]
ary.-(odds)
```

The advantage here is that it is completely chainable (unlike `.delete` or `ary - odds`), so you can do things like:

```
ary.-(odds).average
```

Once your eye finds the minus sign, it's much easier to read, understand, and visually spot typos than the `.delete_if` or `.reject` block constructs.

It also plays well with Ruby's safe navigation operator, `&.`, if you might get nil instead of an array. That's something you can't do elegantly with subtracting arrays.

```
maybe_array&.-(odds)&.average
```